# VS Lightswitch and MS Access DB?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, silverlight, ms-access, visual-studio-lightswitch

Can I use Visual Studio Lightswitch togehter with an MS-Access DB?
If Yes, makes it sense to use it instead of MS-Access for the developing the GUI?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know LightSwitch doesn't support using other datasources in the beta but will in the release. So you're out of luck with MS Access for now.
Does it make sense... sure if you're more proficient in LightSwitch then MS Access.
And LightSwitch has a lot of functionallity to set up your UI faster than MS Access, so I would think so.

Comment: I dispute the "set up your UI faster than MS Access." It betrays the opinions of someone who likely doesn't know how to use Access, which is very fast for setting up UI.

Comment: Well trying out both LightSwitch and MS Access I got my UI up faster in the former. Especially how it looks. So maybe it was subjective on my part, but so might yours.

Answer (score 0):

Out of the box You can not use access as the data source. The system supports SQL Server, Sharepoint, SQL Server Azure and WCF Ria Services. The SQL Server can be either local or remote.

If you do want to use access I suppose you could use a wrapper around the database file and expose it as a WCF RIA Service, but I would just upsize the database to SQL Server or SQL Server Express.

Comment: A SQL Server linked server could get you the ability to use the Jet/ACE data store.